# What does this piece of AJAX code mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I searched the internet for information but I cant seem to get any information about this AJAX piece of code i'm using:

```
function getEmployeeFilterOptions(){
    var opts = [];
    $checkboxes.each(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            opts.push(this.name);
        }
    });
```

Also what is the difference between this code since they are both ways to call of AJAX ?

```
function updateEmployees(opts){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        dataType : 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {filterOpts: opts},
        success: function(records){
            $('#employees tbody').html(makeTable(records));
        }
    });
```

It would be nice if someone could explain in detail what everything stands for.

Comment: There's no ajax in the first snippet..

Comment: what is the relation between this 2 methods? first one is not an ajax call

Comment: The first code snippet loops through a collection of elements, tests a condition on each one, and adds the ones which pass that condition to an array.  The second code snippet sends a POST request to a server-side resource and updates the page with the response.  The two are entirely different in every way.

Answer (score 0):

#### The First Code

The first code is just a pseudo code, or what you say an algorithm code to check for the checkness of a checkbox input element.

```
function getEmployeeFilterOptions(){
    var opts = [];
    $checkboxes.each(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            opts.push(this.name);
        }
    });
});
```

This would check for each of the checkbox, note the `.each()` method. It would execute a function for each element. And will check for a condition. But note, checkboxes won't do anything. You're morelikely to check it as:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
  /* here if else statement */
}
```

#### The Second Code

The second code is the real code to do an ajax request execution.

```
function updateEmployees(opts) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'submit.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {
          filterOpts: opts
        },
        success: function(records) {
          $('#employees tbody').html(makeTable(records));
        }
    });
});
```

This code will send an AJAX request, just like a form submission with `method="post"`, for this you can see the `type: 'POST'` part of the code. Next is the URL of the page, where the page is found to capture the request. The datatype is also the mime of the page, which is set to json. Server would know that the request is in json format. You can handle it on the server side too. Such as:

```
if(request_type == 'json') {
  /* note, it is also a pseudo code */
}
```

Then, the cache is set to false, so that the browser and the server must not and must never save the session of this request.

Data is some other response or QueryString added to the HttpRequest. For example, if the request were GET (`type: 'GET'`). Then you can add the data of your name or anyother as:

```
data: 'user_name=yourname&password=password'
```

This would be added to the url.

Next is a function to be executed if the response was a success. If there was no error found, then this function would execute and the table would be updated!

Comment: Thank you for your explaination, this clarifies things a bit more for me ! Since these functions are for checkboxes, could you tell me how to make this work for a textbox onchange when you start to type a name in the textbox ?

Comment: I really think, you need to learn jQuery first of all..:) http://jquery.com .. then you will know how to select the elements! :) however, you can use this: `$('textarea').change(function () { ... })` ...

Comment: Yes indeed your correct, I need to learn allot of everything about this programming im aware :) But thanks for your piece of code and advice, I wil certainly give it a try !

Comment: Yes, you're most welcome! :) You can try and learn some here: http://basicsofwebdevelopment.wordpress.com/ :) I hope, you'll find it easy ...